# How to assert one of two selectors with capybara + minitest

Tags: ruby, selenium, automation, capybara, minitest

I currently have a def that does this below, but i feel this is inefficient and there could be another way to do it. I know Rspec has the or() function to help it, but capybara doesn't seem to have this.

```
def assert_either_selector(selector_1, selector_2)
  if has_selector?(selector_1, wait: false)
    assert_selector(selector_1)
  elsif has_selector?(selector_2, wait: false)
    assert_selector(selector_2)
  else
    flunk("Failed to match either selector \nExpected to find either: \n\t#{selector_1} or #{selector_2}")
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Capybara does support `or` but only when using RSpec matchers (`expect(page).to have_selector(selector_1).or(have_selector(selector_2))`)  since minitest doesn't have simultaneous evaluation `or` support. Assuming `selector_1` and `selector_2` are CSS selectors then the easiest solution here is to use the CSS comma and do

```
assert_selector("#{selector_1}, #{selector_2}")
```

which will check for an element matching either of the two selectors.

Comment: @Nils_e Note: the next Capybara release (3.10) will probably (it's in the master branch currently) have assert_any_of_selectors to complement the already existing assert_all_of_selectors and assert_none_of_selectors so that will be able to be used for the same thing.